# AVX unpackhipd/unpacklopd analogue for whole 256 bit register

Tags: c, sse, simd, avx

assuming I have two 256-bit registers of four double values, `x` and `y`. output of `_mm256_unpacklo_pd(x, y)` (`VUNPCKLPD`) is: `[x0, y0, x2, y2]` (because every 128-bit line is processed separately). I want to achieve `[x0, y0, x1, y1]`.

Is there any intrinsic/instruction for this? Or, if not, what is the fastest way to achieve desired result?

Comment: Do you need something that works with only AVX1?  Or is AVX2 fine?  (Either way, I don't think there's a single-instruction way to do this until AVX512 2-source lane-crossing shuffles (`vpermt2q`)).

Comment: AVX1 solution is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that all the values you want are in the low lane of your input vectors.

`_mm_unpacklo_pd` / `_mm_unpackhi_pd` on the 128b low halves of each input would set you up for `vinsertf128`.  (If tuning for Sandybridge/Ivybridge, you could use integer shuffles (`vpunpcklqdq / hqdq`) for the 128b ops to get better throughput than FP shuffles.  Since I think this wouldn't hurt on any CPUs that support AVX1, it's not a bad idea.)

If you need the same thing for the high and low lanes, then use 256b in-lane unpack instructions and shuffle the 128b lanes of that result.  `_m256_permute2f128_pd` compiles to `vinsertf128` when possible with gcc/clang, but not with ICC or MSVC, so it's more efficient to write

```
// much faster on Ryzen/KNL, same on Intel mainstream
__m256d lohalves_insert(__m256d lo, __m256d hi) {
    return _mm256_insertf128_pd(lo, _mm256_castpd256_pd128(hi), 1);
}
```

See how various compilers optimize this stuff on [the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%0A//+clang+and+gcc+already+optimize+this+to+a+vinsertf128%0A//+icc+and+MSVC+/Ox+/Gv+don!'t%0A__m256d+lohalves_perm(__m256d+lo,+__m256d+hi)+%7B%0A++++return+_mm256_permute2f128_pd(lo,+hi,+0x20)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+much+faster+on+Ryzen/KNL,+same+on+Intel+mainstream%0A__m256d+lohalves_insert(__m256d+lo,+__m256d+hi)+%7B%0A++++return+_mm256_insertf128_pd(lo,+_mm256_castpd256_pd128(hi),+1)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+slow+on+Ryzen,+but+separate+extract/insert+would+be+slower+on+Intel%0A__m256d+hihalves(__m256d+lo,+__m256d+hi)+%7B%0A++++return+_mm256_permute2f128_pd(lo,hi,+0x13)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A__m128d+extract(__m256d+v)+%7B%0A++++return+_mm256_extractf128_pd(v,+0)%3B%0A++++//+This+compiles+to+a+vzeroupper,+but+only%0A++++//+++because+it+doesn!'t+return+a+256b+vector%0A++++//+It!'s+not+using+vzeroupper+to+implement+the+extract%3B%0A++++//+++it+compiles+to+zero+instructions.%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:37.311385459533604,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(___0:(),b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0',jquery:'3.2.1',length:1,prevObject:(___0:(sizzle1504553323487:(undefined:(legend:!(5,0,'1')))),length:1,prevObject:(___0:(jQuery321088578577632909221:(display:''),sizzle1504553323487:(undefined:(legend:!(5,0,'1')))),length:1))),options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B14+-O3+-Wall+-Wextra+-march%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),header:(),k:29.917070862131503,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang400,filters:(___0:(),b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0',jquery:'3.2.1',length:1,prevObject:(___0:(sizzle1504553323487:(undefined:(legend:!(7484,0,'1')))),length:1,prevObject:(___0:(jQuery321088578577632909221:(display:''),sizzle1504553323487:(undefined:(legend:!(7484,0,'1')))),length:1))),options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B14+-O3+-Wall+-Wextra+-march%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+4.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),k:32.77154367833488,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

---

There might be a 2-instruction way to get it done with only AVX1, but probably not.

---

With AVX2, you could `vinsertf128` to get the low 128b of each input into two lanes of a single vector.  Then use AVX2 [`vpermpd`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VPERMPD.html) to shuffle elements across lanes into their final positions.

This is worse on Ryzen than two 128b `vunpckl/hpd` + `vinsertf128`, but better throughput on Intel.  Still worse latency for 2 lane-crossing shuffles (3+3c = 6c) vs. 1+1(resource conflict)+3c = 5c for the 3-shuffle way, on Intel Haswell and later, or on Sandybridge/Ivybridge if you don't use integer shuffles for the 128b ops.  (See Agner Fog's insn tables, links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.)

Comment: won't working on 128-bit lines use sse instead of avx?

Comment: No, not if you compile with `-mavx`.  Then `_mm_unpacklo_pd` will compile to `vunpcklpd xmm2, xmm0, xmm1` for example.  In C you need a bunch of cast intrinsics; it's unfortunately less convenient than in assembly language.  2x unpack xmm / `vinsertf128` should be good for Ryzen, BTW, since it decodes 256b instructions into 2 uops each.

Comment: Thing is, I need to provide versions for both sse and av to be chosen at runtime. And I hope it wont change modes

Comment: @AndreiR.: put the SSE version in a file you compile without `-mavx`.  You need to use `-mavx` or the MSVC equivalent while compiling files that use AVX intrinsics to avoid risk of mixing SSE and AVX.  And you need to *not* use it when compiling legacy SSE functions.

Comment: even though I found another solution, your answer was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @AndreiR.: You mean instead of shuffling like this in your code?  If you have a better way to do this shuffle, please post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I actually need both high/low parts of processed data, so it takes four instructions for two vectors: unpackhi/unpacklo and shuffling their low/high halves

Comment: So `_mm256_unpacklo/hi_pd`, then combine those results 2 different ways with `vinsertf128` for the low lanes, and `vperm2f128` for high lanes.  (`vperm2f128` is very slow on Ryzen, and some compilers won't optimize `_mm256_permute2f128_pd(a,b,0)` to a `vinsertf128`, so it makes sense to cast and use `_mm256_insertf128_pd`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, according to [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=AVX&expand=3894,2958,2277&text=extract), `vperm2f128` is at least twice faster than `vextractf128`+`vinsertf128` pair. And twice slower on AMD. Seems that in my case it'd be both faster and simpler to use `vperm2f128`

Comment: You don't need a `vextractf128` instruction to get the low lane of a vector.  It's already directly accessible as the corresponding xmm register.  https://godbolt.org/g/dZx7qX.  Turns out gcc and clang both optimize `_mm256_permute2f128_pd(lo, hi, 0x20);` to a `vinsertf128`.  Also, `_mm256_extractf128_pd(v, 0);` compiles to zero instructions.  That's why I didn't suggest using vextract/vinsert for the high halves: it would be faster on Ryzen but slower on Intel instead of the same.